# javascript new Date and UTC date give same UTC time

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaSCript code:

```
function getDate() {
    return new Date().toJSON();
}

function getUtcDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var now_utc = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return new Date(now_utc).toJSON();
}
```

Bothe are returning the same date time, I was expecting getDate() to return my local time.. it doesn't as you can see in the image

[image]
I uploaded a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qw2ct7fj/).

Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Comment: `toJSON` doesn't say anything about returning your local time - `The toJSON() method returns a string representation of the Date object.`

Comment: @goto1 obviouse that's a "to-string" method, the getUtcDate function makes UTC, it does that just fine, only issue is that getDate() also returns UTC

Comment: You mean your custom `getDate` or the `getDate` method on a `Date` instance? I am not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @WalterVehoeven _Date.prototype.toJSON()
Returns a string representing the Date using toISOString(). Intended for use by JSON.stringify()._ So even if you created a date using `new Date()` it will string return date in UTC format

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDate() {
  return new Date().toLocaleString();
}

function getDateOffset() {
  return new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
}

function getUtcDate() {
  return new Date().toUTCString();
}


console.log('Local Date = '+ getDate());
console.log('local TimeZone Offset = '+ getDateOffset())
console.log('UTC Date = '+ getUtcDate());
```

---

**Updated**

```js
var date = moment.utc().format();
console.log(date, "UTC"); 

var local = moment.utc(date).local().format();// add parameter to format to remove Timezone Offset 
console.log(local, "UTC to Local + TimeZone Offset");

console.log('---------------------------------------------');
// you can use .format() from momentjs to return any format you want
var formattedDate = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a'); 
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```